# Does NirSoft utilities have a virus?

Tags: virus

I downloaded NirSoft utilities from a trustworthy link on HowToGeek and both Avast and Windows Defender claim they contain a virus, however I'm unsure if it is a false positive.

Does anyone have any information on this?

Comment: With no link & no followable paper-trail, neither do we. Test the file on virustotal.com & see what the consensus is.

Comment: Try downloading directly from NirSoft (https://www.nirsoft.net/).  Be aware that low-level utilities often get flagged as viruses because the mechanisms they use may be similar.  (But that doesn't mean that they haven't been infected.)

Comment: *"I downloaded NirSoft utilities."*  You'll receive better answers if you don't withhold key information, such as the name of the tools you downloaded. Which utilities did you *actually* download? They have 46 on their site. https://www.nirsoft.net.

Comment: Nirsoft developed several utilities that _could_ be used maliciously and is why many antivirus/anti-malware software will barf a warning with some of their programs are malware _(e.g. password extraction utilities, web browser database utilities for sniffing through a browser's account, etc., however all of their programs have legitimate uses)_

Answer (score 5):

No. Nirsoft tools do NOT contain viruses. I use quite a number of them (nirsoft.net) and (a) no issues and (b) Windows Defender does not detect as any kind of virus. Safe to use.

Comment: Certain Nirsoft programs will usually cause antivirus/anti-malware to barf malware errors due to the potential for specific Nirsoft programs to be used maliciously _(e.g. password extraction utilities, web browser database utilities for sniffing through a browser's account, etc.)_, even though all of Nirsoft's programs have legitimate uses and are not malware in-and-of themselves

Comment: There are a variety of programs (unlocker, old versions of Sync Back) that come up on Windows Defender, but as you correctly note, Nirsoft Tools are a legitimate group of programs. I just Whitelist what I have to.

Answer (score 0):

NO. That was definitely a false alarm.

NirSoft is a well known and trusted name like Winternal's Sysinternals (acquired by Microsoft in 2006). I've been using them for decades.

Furthermore, these are utilities which are flagged as virus/trojan.

```
operapassview.exe
passwordscan.exe
produkey.exe
pstpassword.exe
rdpv.exe
```

All of them reveal sensitive info (passwords/product keys) on your system.

You can temporarily turned off the real-time protection setting, to extract those incorrectly flagged files. The setting will automatically turned back on after few minutes (I'm not sure maybe 5 or 10 minutes).

```
Settings
-> Windows Security
  -> Virus Threat & Protection
    -> Virus Threat & Protection Settings
      -> Manage Settings
        -> Real-time protection (TURN OFF)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I can't say for sure, but I find it VERY suspicious that Nirsoft offers its binaries in password-protected `.zip` files. It is something I would mainly expect for a hidden virus.

I can imagine no other reason in this case to password protect a `.zip` file, other than to conceal its contents from a virus scanner:

- [Nirsoft:](https://www.nirsoft.net/x64_download_package.html)

  > You can download the entire package in zip file from here. The password to extract the files is `nirsoft123!`

Comment: If there is a virus, it will be discovered when the files are extracted. So, I don't think that securing the zip file with a password means that the file is suspicious.

Comment: Password-protecting the archive lets you download the file without antivirus noticing, so you can deal with the extraction separately. A regular archive wouldn't even download, which could be harder to bypass.

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, you will download it without antivirus noticing. But wouldn't the antivirus notice during extraction?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes. But the antivirus would probably display a popup that lets you restore the quarantined file (relatively) easily, while browsers tend to make it rather hard. Also you could eg. store such file on a flash drive and not get it deleted when you connect this drive to a random PC.